# parsing HTTP request parameter

Tags: spring-boot, rest, http

I want to pass a physical path from a file server to a web service using Spring boot Rest API
the path I want to send is
E:\\sharedFile\\data
I am sending my parameter as @RequistParam like so

```
    @PostMapping("/loadPicturesIntoDB")
    public ResponseEntity<String> loadDB(@RequestParam String path) {
        int size = imageService.loadDB(path);
        return new ResponseEntity<String>("the database has been loaded with" + size + " files from the provided path ",
                HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

I am getting the following error

```
2020-10-03 15:18:34.273  INFO 17356 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor   : Error parsing HTTP request header
Note: further occurrences of HTTP request parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in the request target [image/loadPicturesIntoDB?path=%22E:\\sharedFile\\data%22]. The valid characters are defined in RFC 7230 and RFC 3986
   at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:486) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
   at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:261) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
   at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
   at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_231]
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_231]
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_231]
```

Thanks in advance guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sending URL in request parameter will be problematic as tomcat by default do not perform encoding.

I would recommend you to send this as part of Request body instead.